# Mongo: $or query looking for multiple possible values in the same field

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection on mongo called "reports", which has the ability for customers to comment on and have discussions.

Here is how the "discussions" array looks like in each report:

```
"discussions" : [
    {
        "user_id" : "david",
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-03-17T01:15:00Z"),
        "comment" : "I was wondering, did anyone else find it interesting?",
        "replies" : [
            {
                "user_id" : "kevin",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-03-17T01:15:00Z"),
                "comment" : "Not really"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As the displayed information on the users above each comment often change, I want to use referencing and pull their information from the "users" collection based on the "user_id" fields, instead of embedding their information in each discussion post.
I want to have the flexibility to shard the entire database, so "$lookup" is probably a no-go (as, if I understand correctly, the "from" field in "$lookup" cannot be sharded).

Therefore, I want to build an '$or' query that will be similar to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE id IN ('david', 'kevin')
```

and that will pull the additional user information from the users collection, then combine them with the rest of the comment details on the application level.

For that reason, the query I push to find() is built by the application, by iterating over the results from "reports" and extracting the "user_id".
This is how the var_dump of the query looks like:

```
array(1) {
  ["$or"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["_id"]=>
      string(4) "david"
    },
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(4) "kevin"
    }
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as I get no results despite having those users in the database.
Note: the _id of the users in the "users" collection is the username.

Am I doing the $or query incorrectly (all I see in the documentation is '$or' performed on different fields)?
Is there a better way to pull this off entirely?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

You should rather use an in-query for that. In mongo-syntax:

```
db.users.find({ "_id" : { $in : [ "david", "kevin" ] } })
```

Comment: is the following syntax considered the same? `db.users.find({ "_id" :  [ "david", "kevin" ]  })` ?

Comment: @Normal No, that would signify that "_id" is an array of exactly the values "david" and "kevin" in that order. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/